# How to check if two moving objects collide each other IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a problem in `UIDynamicBehavior`. I am using `UIPushBehavior` for moving two objects in different directions.

I want to print "Collide" when they get collide.

Which method gets called when two moving objects collide?

`UIDynamicAnimator`
`UICollisionBehavior`
`UIPushBehavior`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make the class you want to handle the collision implement UICollisionBehaviorDelegate, so in your header file you would change your interface line to `@interface MyClassHere : MySuperclass <UICollisionBehaviorDelegate>`. For your collision behavior, when you are initializing it use `collisionBehavior.delegate = self;` then add the method `- (void)collisionBehavior:(UICollisionBehavior *)behavior beganContactForItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item1 withItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item2 atPoint:(CGPoint)p` which will be called every time a collision happens between two items that are part of UICollisionBehavior. 
So your method would look like:

```
- (void)collisionBehavior:(UICollisionBehavior *)behavior beganContactForItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item1 withItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item2 atPoint:(CGPoint)p{
NSLog(@"Collide");
}
```

Hope it helps :)